# Nginx logical AND operator

Tags: nginx

How do you write an Nginx rule to redirect all non-https requests to https, except for a certain path?

I have a health-check path that's not under SSL, but I want everything else to be redirected to SSL, so I need a rule like:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' && $request_uri != "/check.html") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

but that gives me a syntax error. Google shows several examples for doing logical OR expressions, but nothing for AND. Is this supported in Nginx?

Edit: This server sits behind a load balancer, and all requests are forwarded on port 80, even if the original request is https. I also need this redirect to work with a uwsgi application configured like:

```
location / {   
    uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/myapp.sock;
    include     /usr/local/myapp/uwsgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$request_uri != "/check.html"` part can be converted to a pair of `location` blocks. And place a simple `if` block within one of those.

For example:

```
location / {
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    ...
}
location = /check.html {
    ...
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: I already have a rule for "/" that includes `uwsgi_pass` to direct everything to a Python web app. Adding the redirect before that appears to completely disable the app, even though all requests are under https, which would presumably not activate the if statement.

Comment: Are you testing this via the reverse proxy? Do you know that the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is being set? If your want this to work even if `X-Forwarded-Proto` is not set, you might want to change the `if` to `$http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'`

Comment: Yes. This was working fine via Apache. Now I'm trying to do the same with Nginx, and I'm finding it doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may use string concatination to achieve the effect of logical **AND**,

```
set $str '$http_x_forwarded_proto $request_uri';
if ($str != 'https /check.html') {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

use regular expression to achieve the effect of logical **OR**, or mixed **AND**, **OR**, **NOT**

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS conditionally
# 301 Moved Permanently (for methods GET, HEAD)
# 308 Permanent Redirect (for methods except GET, HEAD)
set $exp "$http_upgrade_insecure_requests $request_method";
if ($exp ~ "^1 (GET|HEAD)$") {
  add_header vary upgrade-insecure-requests;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
if ($exp ~ "^1 (?!GET|HEAD)$") {
  add_header vary upgrade-insecure-requests;
  return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```